# Most efficient / pythonic way of finding text between two words and replacing it

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a more pythonic / efficient way of finding and replacing text between two words in a string?

```
string = "<start>processing<end>"

# Create start and stop indexes to get text between two words
start = string.find("<start>") + len("<start>")
end = string.find("<end>")
substrig = string[start:end]

# Update the word
string = string.replace(substrig, "Shipped")

print(string)
# Prints <start>Shipped<end>
```

Comment: yes. It's called [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: alternative option: use an existing formatting or templating engine, if you can (can be as simple as string.format, all the way to the complexity of jinja2)

Comment: Use regular expressions.